# Learning Oracle and GeoSpatial Systems

Tags: oracle, geospatial

Lately, I am getting more engrossed in learning Oracle and Geospatial systems. I feel that mapping systems, combined with solid data structure are two technologies that are making their niche in today's market.

If you are starting to learn about these technologies, where would you recommend starting off?  If I understand correctly, the best way to learn them would be through actual work (or hobby), but I can't seem to find good places to get the resources to do so.

I would appreciate any advice, tips, resources and information everyone could provide to jump-start my learning and understanding of these technologies.

Thanks.

Update:
Saw a nice PDF relating about this, but for a hobbyist wanting to learn it, are there free tools to start off with it?

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/mapviewer/pdf/mv11g_spatialvis_inobiee.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be interested in OLAP/BI combined with GIS/mapping.

See information on **Spatial OLAP** (aka SOLAP) at **http://www.spatialbi.org/** , as well as this list of tools at http://spatialolap.scg.ulaval.ca/DevApproaches.asp

Also, see **GeoKettle** at **http://www.spatialytics.org/**